# Segfault in shared_ptr destructor

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, destructor, shared-ptr

#### Context

I am trying to make a small game engine and currently I'm working on an entity component system. I have an array of shared pointers to Model objects (3D models read from OBJ files). I then connect the models with entities using a model component that essentially has a struct of two arrays, one with entity handles and the other with indices to models. The indices refer to elements of a vector in the component with the actual shared pointers to the models. I do this to not have to construct the shared pointers in dynamically allocated memory.

I have two classes for models, base class `Model` and a specialised subclass `UntexturedModel` that stores the vertex position data in a more efficient way. For testing I am now using two entities and assigning the first one a `Model` object and the other `UntexturedModel` object (to make sure both behave correctly with this system).

#### Problem

The actual component behaviour works as intended, the model is correctly connected with the entity and retrieved when rendering. But when the `main` function terminates, there is a segfault. I used Valgrind to try and figure out where the problem was, and it says there is an Invalid Jump from `std::default_delete<Model>::operator()(Model*)`.

I have tried creating a separate shared pointer of the exact same type and resetting it immediately, which AFAIK should trigger the same problem, but it goes through smoothly. After a couple similar tests (using only the base class model, using only one model for both entities, adding a custom deleter that calls `~Model` and then deletes the pointer) I am fairly certain that the problem only occurs after the `main` function terminates.

I can add any code snippets, just ask which ones.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Instead of posting just small code-snippets that can be hard to put together, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem and which you can show us. Simplifying helps not only us, but it will also help you as well. It might even lead to you being able to find the problem yourself.

Comment: Rather than post snippets, it would be most helpful if you could find a [mcve]. One way of doing that is to copy the project somewhere else, and start pulling out as much unrelated code as you can, as long as the same problem still happens.

Comment: You may be running into memory corruption, and the corruption symptom is is segfaulting in the shared_ptr destructor.  The cause-and-effect separated by time and space, making it extra fun to debug.

Comment: I am afraid after you would be ready with a [mcve], you would find the issue in your code yourself without our help.

Comment: Also, Valgrind doesn't say anything else? There's no out-of-bounds access anywhere? No warning when you build, not even if you enable much more warnings?

Comment: @S.M. one of the way to find the problem

Comment: Are you sure you don't have threads still running at main() exit? That may cause UB. is it bound to some  graphics API (e.g. OpenGL?) already? segfault might be caused by still running thread because you destroyed bound buffers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Valgrind only says this one Invalid Jump, and then a couple Leak_DefinitelyLost and UninitCondition but those are in the libraries I'm using.

Comment: @Swift I haven't started any threads but one of the libraries I use might have. I use OpenGL and the models contain the buffer and VAO IDs and delete them in the destructor.

Comment: Is there any chance that OpenGL is "taking ownership" for any of the things you're freeing in the destructor? Look at any of the places you pass pointers into OpenGL... maybe OpenGL needs to be told that you're going to manage these resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been trying to delete OpenGL objects (VAOs and VBOs) in the `Model` destructor after the `main` function, because at that point, the OpenGL context has been terminated. Forcing destruction by putting the model component manager in a unique pointer and resetting that after the main loop finished but before the OpenGL context is terminated led to no more invalid jumps.

Thank you to @Swift for pointing me in the right direction.